# How to Translate Nested If/AND Statements into MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips

As part of a class project I'm working on, a debug feature must be included.  I'm having trouble with some if/and statements.  This is what I wrote:

/*previous code to find where status matrix contains a 1*/

```
`beq  s0, 1, _debug_mode  #debug feature is ON if s0 contains 1
_debug_mode:  
li   a0, 0            #tile flipped to say NOT revealed
_else:  
li   a0, 1
```

`
I'm not getting the results I'm expecting, so my thinking is that the code is written incorrectly.  Any insight would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works out to the smallest C code of:

```
if (debug) 
    status = !status;
```

In MIPS, this can be written (assuming s0 is debug, and a0 is status):

```
  blez s0, no_debug_mode
  xori a0, a0, 1
no_debug_mode:
   # ...
```

Or more verbosely

```
  blez s0, no_debug_mode
  blez a0, set_status_high
  li a0, 0
  j no_debug_mode
set_status_high:
  li a0, 1
no_debug_mode:
  # ...
```

The example you have posted only branches on one of the values and does not use a negation, so it will give the wrong results.  Further, you don't have a jump at the end of your `_debug_mode` label, so the `_else` will *always* execute.

It has been a while since I've done MIPS.  If there are branch delay slots required, those would have to be added to both of the above answers.

Comment: Real MIPS has branch-delay slots (unless you use MIPS32/64r6 no-delay branch instructions).  Many people doing MIPS homework program for MARS or SPIM with branch-delay slots disabled.  But the syntax in the question isn't using `$a0`, just plain `a0`, so it might not be either of those assemblers / simulators.  But yes, good answer, factoring out the `debug==1` precondition is possible in this case, simplifying everything.  Otherwise there are duplicate Q&As about the general case.  e.g. slt or whatever into registers that you combine with AND or OR.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was helpful.

Comment: @Nikki, glad to hear it.  You might consider using the checkmark to the left of the answer to accept it.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers